# How to get apache to look for files in different subfolders folders?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am definitely new to mod-rewrite stuff.

Note:- here the URL is common, and all the folders and subfolders on same host.

The url a user uses to access their page is `http://myurl.com/1234/filename.jpg`

Here the name of the subfolder is an integer is unique and generated dynamically by another application.

The subfolder stores images specific to an individual user.

So the folder structure is as follows

```
main1 = document root
main2 is another folder within main1 or document root.

/main1/1234/filename.jpg
/main1/5678/filename.jpg
/main1/2345/filename.jpg
/main1/1212/filename.jpg
/main1/main2/2367/filename.jpg
/main1/main2/8790/filename.jpg
/main1/main2/9966/filename.jpg
```

So, I want to write a rewrite a rule so that if a user tries to type in

```
http://myurl.com/1234/filename.jpg,
```

the rewrite rule will need to look where the file is and serve the request; so for request http:/myurl.com/1234/filename.jpg the actual page is located at /main1/1234/filename.jpg and then need to serve that page from that folder.

So, if another users makes a request as http://myurl.com/9966/filename.jpg, it should serve the page from the following destination /main1/main2/9966/filename.jpg

Please let me know if the question is still not clear.

This is what i have done so far and does not work at all.

```
RewriteCond         {DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ {DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1  [L]  
RewriteCond         {DOCUMENT_ROOT}/main2/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ {DOCUMENT_ROOT}/main2/$1  [L]
```

any help is really grateful

EDIT
@ShaneMadden please find the details 
The config is located in the .htaccess file; please find the .htaccess details

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/main1/\/. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(main1)(/\/.+)$ $1/main2/\$2
```

EDIT:

Olivier, thanks for helping me. please find the details as below..

***httpd.conf***

```
DocumentRoot  "/WebServer/Documents"
```

***Directory Listing***

```
ls -lRt /WebServer/Documents/

-rw-r--r--   index.html 
-rw-r--r--   .htaccess
drwxrwxrwx main1
drwxrwxrwx 456231 (Is a folder)


./WebServer/Documents/main1/:
drwxrwxrwx 566432

./WebServer/Documents/456231/:
-rwxrwxrwx  one.jpg

./WebServer/Documents/main1/566432:
-rwxrwxrwx one.jpg
```

***.htaccess Files***

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f
RewriteRule  (.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1  [L]
RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/main1/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f
RewriteRule  (.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/main1/$1  [L]
```

***Access URL's --> http://localhost:80/***

```
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:52:54 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#1009918a8/initial] (3) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] strip per-dir prefix: /WebServer/Documents/ -> 
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:52:54 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#1009918a8/initial] (3) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri ''
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:52:54 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#1009918a8/initial] (4) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] RewriteCond: input='/WebServer/Documents//WebServer/Documents/' pattern='-f' => not-matched
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:52:54 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#1009918a8/initial] (3) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] strip per-dir prefix: /WebServer/Documents/ -> 
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:52:54 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#1009918a8/initial] (3) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri ''
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:52:54 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#1009918a8/initial] (4) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] RewriteCond: input='/WebServer/Documents/main1//WebServer/Documents/' pattern='-f' => not-matched
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:52:54 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#1009918a8/initial] (1) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] pass through /WebServer/Documents/
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:52:54 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#10099c8a8/subreq] (3) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] strip per-dir prefix: /WebServer/Documents/index.html -> index.html
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:52:54 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#10099c8a8/subreq] (3) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'index.html'
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:52:54 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#10099c8a8/subreq] (4) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] RewriteCond: input='/WebServer/Documents//WebServer/Documents/index.html' pattern='-f' => not-matched
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:52:54 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#10099c8a8/subreq] (3) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] strip per-dir prefix: /WebServer/Documents/index.html -> index.html
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:52:54 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#10099c8a8/subreq] (3) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'index.html'
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:52:54 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#10099c8a8/subreq] (4) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] RewriteCond: input='/WebServer/Documents/main1//WebServer/Documents/index.html' pattern='-f' => not-matched
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:52:54 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#10099c8a8/subreq] (1) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] pass through /WebServer/Documents/index.html
```

***2.) http://localhost:80/566432/one.jpg***

```
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:59:28 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#1009918a8/initial] (3) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] add path info postfix: /WebServer/Documents/566432 -> /WebServer/Documents/566432/one.jpg
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:59:28 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#1009918a8/initial] (3) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] strip per-dir prefix: /WebServer/Documents/566432/one.jpg -> 566432/one.jpg
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:59:28 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#1009918a8/initial] (3) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri '566432/one.jpg'
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:59:28 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#1009918a8/initial] (4) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] RewriteCond: input='/WebServer/Documents//WebServer/Documents/566432' pattern='-f' => not-matched
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:59:28 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#1009918a8/initial] (3) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] add path info postfix: /WebServer/Documents/566432 -> /WebServer/Documents/566432/one.jpg
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:59:28 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#1009918a8/initial] (3) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] strip per-dir prefix: /WebServer/Documents/566432/one.jpg -> 566432/one.jpg
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:59:28 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#1009918a8/initial] (3) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri '566432/one.jpg'
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:59:28 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#1009918a8/initial] (4) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] RewriteCond: input='/WebServer/Documents/main1//WebServer/Documents/566432' pattern='-f' => not-matched
::1 - - [26/Nov/2011:10:59:28 +0000] [localhost/sid#10090f128][rid#1009918a8/initial] (1) [perdir /WebServer/Documents/] pass through /WebServer/Documents/566432
```

Comment: Are the integers split specifically between the two places (ex: 0000-4999 in main1, 5000-9999 in main2)? Or is there only a few dozen integers? If so would be possible to create rewrite rules, otherwise I don't think rewrite rules can actually check the existence of a file like this. Why do you have the content split into two directories like this anyways?

Comment: Actually, it looks like it is possible: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969106/apache-rewrite-if-file-doesnt-exist-check-another-directory

Comment: those integers are random numbers and are folder names. They are not split in any specific order. The folder names which are basically integers are randomly generated on a daily basis from on another application. It is the application logic which requires to split the folders into 2 directories, that is the way the setup is. I was looking for options as i found this article for something i wanted to achieve ; but could not succeed much http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html The Section "Search pages in more than one directory" is the one i was trying to achieve..

Comment: i tried but still does not work, any more help please?         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/main1/\/.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(main1)(/\/.+)$ $1/main2$2

Comment: @prb Can you edit your question with the ruleset you're attempting?  It's getting a bit hard to follow.  Also - where is this config located?

Comment: @ShaneMadden please find the details </br>the config is located in the .htaccess file,</br> please find the .htaccess details </br>  > RewriteEngine on
</br>  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/main1/\/.
  </br> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 </br> RewriteRule ^(main1)(/\/.+)$ $1/main2/\$2

Comment: @shane, i have tried 2 rule sets ; posted on this page, none is working.

Answer (score 1):

You almost did it!!

You forgot the "%" !!

And `^(.*)$` alone is the same as `(.*)` so here's what should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f
RewriteRule  (.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1  [L]  
RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/main2/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f
RewriteRule  (.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/main2/$1  [L]
```

Tell me if it works ;)

Comment: I tried but still does not work..

Comment: I think that might work if you remove the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` from the RewriteRule (you may also need to remove it from the RewriteCond).

Comment: tried that as well, not working.

Comment: one more thing, i have enabled logging and notice that the lookup it is doing is incorrect, would you be able to advice what needs changing here?  RewriteCond: input='/main1/one.html/main2/' pattern='-f' => not-matched

Comment: *incorrect = the lookup for the page..

Comment: could you please add your logs to your question (with the URLs you're typing in the browser)?